# "Connection refused" although server is listening

Tags: connection, client-server

I have a server listening on certain port on `127.0.0.1 and 18 local clients` who try to connect to it all the time concurrently.

**After an hour or so of ongoing connections**, one of the clients fails to connect (I use the C function connect() which returns -1 when fails) and `WSAGetLastError` returns `10061` which means "Connection refused".

I read that one possible reason for this error to appear is server not listening on the correct port, but I print `netstat -an` command line output to a file at the same moment I try to connect and I can see that the server is listening on the correct port.

Furthermore, when I try to reconnect or to connect from another application, I succeed.
Do any of you know what might be the reason for the client to fail to connect even though the server is listening?

BTW, I'm running on `Windows 7`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague. But when you run `netstat -ab` you'll see the listening services. If the IP address is `127.0.0.1` the service will only listen to connections from the local machine only. If the IP address is `0.0.0.0` it is listening on all IP addresses for incoming connections. And if it displays an IP address that isn't `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0` it is listening for connections only on that IP address.

So if you have 18 remote clients connecting to a server that is listening to the local IP address, the clients will fail to connect since the server is not listening for connections remotely.

Comment: The clients are local, and notice that it happens only "After an hour or so of ongoing connections"

Comment: @user3737723 Then I think you'll need to post some code of client and/or server so we can understand how it connects.